# Why don't edges added with G.add_edges_from(), match G.edges()?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

### Scenario

- Using `networkx`
- Given an empty graph `G`
- Add a list of tuples called `edges` to `G`

  - `len(edges)` is 119
- `G.edges()` doesn't match `edges`

  - `len(G.edges())` is 112, but my expectation is it should be 119
  - the node combinations do not match `edges`, but my expectation is they should match

### Code

```py
import networkx as nx

edges = [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14), (1, 15), (1, 16), (1, 17), (1, 18), (1, 19), (1, 20), (1, 21), (1, 22), (1, 23), (1, 24), (1, 25), (1, 26), (1, 27), (1, 28), (1, 29), (1, 30), (1, 31), (1, 32), (1, 33), (1, 34), (1, 35), (1, 36), (1, 37), (1, 38), (1, 39), (1, 40), (1, 41), (1, 42), (1, 43), (1, 44), (1, 45), (1, 46), (1, 47), (1, 48), (1, 49), (16, 18), (16, 35), (16, 36), (16, 48), (18, 16), (18, 24), (18, 35), (18, 36), (19, 5), (19, 8), (19, 11), (19, 13), (19, 15), (19, 17), (19, 20), (19, 21), (19, 24), (19, 30), (19, 31), (19, 35), (19, 36), (19, 37), (19, 48), (28, 1), (28, 5), (28, 7), (28, 8), (28, 11), (28, 14), (28, 15), (28, 17), (28, 20), (28, 21), (28, 24), (28, 25), (28, 27), (28, 29), (28, 30), (28, 31), (28, 35), (28, 36), (28, 37), (28, 44), (28, 48), (28, 49), (36, 5), (36, 24), (36, 35), (36, 37), (37, 24), (37, 35), (37, 36), (39, 1), (39, 24), (39, 33), (39, 35), (39, 36), (39, 38), (39, 40), (39, 41), (39, 45), (42, 1), (43, 24), (43, 29), (43, 35), (43, 36), (43, 37), (43, 47), (43, 48), (45, 1), (45, 39), (45, 41)]

print(len(edges))
>>> 119

# unique index 0 values from each edges tuple
print(set([x[0] for x in edges]))
>>> {1, 16, 18, 19, 28, 36, 37, 39, 42, 43, 45}

# create empty graph
G = nx.Graph()

# add edges
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# get graph edges
ge = G.edges()

# length of ge
print(len(ge))
>>> 112

# unique index 0 values from each ge tuple
print(set([x[0] for x in ge]))
>>>{1, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43}

# output the edges of G
print(ge)
>>> EdgeView([(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14), (1, 15), (1, 16), (1, 17), (1, 18), (1, 19), (1, 20), (1, 21), (1, 22), (1, 23), (1, 24), (1, 25), (1, 26), (1, 27), (1, 28), (1, 29), (1, 30), (1, 31), (1, 32), (1, 33), (1, 34), (1, 35), (1, 36), (1, 37), (1, 38), (1, 39), (1, 40), (1, 41), (1, 42), (1, 43), (1, 44), (1, 45), (1, 46), (1, 47), (1, 48), (1, 49), (5, 19), (5, 28), (5, 36), (7, 28), (8, 19), (8, 28), (11, 19), (11, 28), (13, 19), (14, 28), (15, 19), (15, 28), (16, 18), (16, 35), (16, 36), (16, 48), (17, 19), (17, 28), (18, 24), (18, 35), (18, 36), (19, 20), (19, 21), (19, 24), (19, 30), (19, 31), (19, 35), (19, 36), (19, 37), (19, 48), (20, 28), (21, 28), (24, 28), (24, 36), (24, 37), (24, 39), (24, 43), (25, 28), (27, 28), (28, 29), (28, 30), (28, 31), (28, 35), (28, 36), (28, 37), (28, 44), (28, 48), (28, 49), (29, 43), (33, 39), (35, 36), (35, 37), (35, 39), (35, 43), (36, 37), (36, 39), (36, 43), (37, 43), (38, 39), (39, 40), (39, 41), (39, 45), (41, 45), (43, 47), (43, 48)])
```

### Expectations and questions

1. `edges` and `ge` should have the same length

   - Why don't they?
2. `edges` and `ge` should have the same node combinations

   - Why don't they?
3. Are my expectations incorrect, and if so, why?
4. What, if anything, can be done to make `ge` and `edges` match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're generating an undirected graph, and some of the edges in the edge list are the same just in *reversed* order. You can check this by sorting the sublists, and building a `set` from the result:

```
len(set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in edges))
# 112
```

As you can see you have the same amount of *unique combinations* of nodes as edges in the graph.

If you generated a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Directed_graph) instead, you'd get as you expect, since in this case order *does* matter:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

len(G.edges())
# 119
```